# Adding SQL Date + Numerical

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, report

**Hi All**

Currently I'm generating some sort of reports using SQL Query and have difficulty in adding 2 fields that has different formatting

1 Field is with Date Formatting while the others is numeric

Below will show clear illustrations

[image: Illustration Table]

Basically I want to add 2 fields (Invoice Date & Payment Due) to produce report like this

[image]

I try using query as follow but it failed.

```
SELECT T1.InvDate, T1.PymntDue, T1.InvDate + T1.PymntDue AS 'Payment Due Date'
FROM INV T1
```

It produce the following errors.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I've try convert them but no success.
Appreciate your help

Thank You

Regards
Gerald

Comment: Which database system is it?

Comment: Hi its Microsoft SQL 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight shot in the dark, but based on your error it appears that `PymntDue` is not actually numeric, it is a string.

If that is the case, then you should be able to do:

```
InvDate + CAST(PymntDue AS int)
```

Or:

```
DATEADD(DAY,CAST(PymntDue AS int),InvDate)
```

Or, change the column datatype for `PymntDue` to int/numeric

Comment: Hi Aaron. Thanks a lot it do works. I just wondering if I can use this Query on extra Field I will be create on ERP I'm using. So I will be adding 3 text field. 2 Text field will have Date format, and 1 Text field will have Alphanumeric format. One is definitely Document Date, and Payment Due Date (This will have Date Format) while the other is Alphanumerical. What this due when I enter both Invoice Date and Due Date, Payment Due will fill in automatically. Here the Query I wrote DATEDIFF (DAY, $[InvoiceDate], $[PaymentDueDate]. However I was greeted with the same errors

Comment: It greet me with this error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @GrandBahamut90 Glad it helped.  For your new problem and the original problem, both could be solved by using the "correct" datatypes for the columns.  If you used the `date` or `datetime` type instead of a string type then you would be able to use `DATEDIFF` without issue.  The problem with using string datatypes for a column that you intend to only have dates in, is that someone could input, for example, `ABC` into the column.  `ABC` will never succeed in converting to a date, so you can't use date functions like `DATEDIFF()` without filtering out any non dates first.